# How to duplicate mesh along edge

Tags: modeling, mesh

To begin with im kinda new to blender, so, i found a wheel that i wanted to place in my project, but it had broken lip. In order to fix the rim i wanna to fill the edge with that mesh that is selected, but it seems im too unexpirienced to do that. lol
Can anyone can explain to me how to do that? :D

[image]

Comment: Don't have time to give a full rundown, but using a circular curve object, the curve modifier on the mesh lip, an array modifier, and merging by distance, you might be able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Blender considers  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> Duplicate, followed immediately by a transform, to be a single operation, which can be repeated.

So, with Transform Pivot set to '3D Cursor' at the middle of your wheel, and Snap settings - 'Snap To': Vertex, 'Snap With': Active, and set to influence at least 'Rotation'.. this would be the quick hack, in Vertex mode, with your section of lip selected, and a suitable vertex active ..

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>
- Drag to snap
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> repeat the operation until the rim is filled
- With all verts selected, <kbd>M</kbd> Merge > By Distance.

[image]

(Assuming your wheel's axis is along Z)

Comment: Thank you!!! Much appreciate your fast and fancy answer! :D